# Symfony2 Sonata admin setting query for sonata_type_collection

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Is it possible to set up a query for sonata_type_collection? For example I I simply do this now...

```
        ->add('deal', 'sonata_type_collection',
            array(

                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'product',
            ),
            array(
                'property' => 'product',
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',

            ))
```

This works fine, but the deals that I am showing in the collection have statuses... And I only want to display the deals that have statuses set up to true... How can I do that? Can I set up a query for collection?

The thing is I can do this:

```
        ->add('deal', null, array(
            'by_reference' => false,
            'class' => 'Mp\ShopBundle\Entity\DailyDeal',
            'query_builder' => $this->modelManager->createQuery('Mp\ShopBundle\Entity\DailyDeal', 'h')
                ->where('h.status = 1'),
        ), array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
        ))
```

And this way if is select multiple deals it saves in an array... I want to create a seperate object for every deal I select. Like the sonata_type_collection does..

What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know is to create a property and getter in your Entity that only return your desired values and use it in your Admin class.

**Entity.php**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Entity
{
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="XXX")
    */
    private $dealsActivated;

    public function getDealsActivated()
    {
         $collection = new ArrayCollection();
         foreach ($this->getDeal() as $deal) {
             if ($deal->getStatus() === 1) {
                 $collection->add($deal);
             }
         }

         return $collection;
    }
}
```

**Admin.php**

```
->add('dealsActivated', 'sonata_type_collection',
    array(

        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'product',
    ),
    array(
        'property' => 'product',
        'edit' => 'inline',
        'inline' => 'table',

    )
)
```

It's not optimized but works with Sonata.